# How do I disable the annoying touchpad edge swipe gestures in Windows 10 for generic touchpads?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, tablet, tablet-pc

I need some help in turning off/disabling the touchpad edge swipe gestures in my Windows 10 2-in-1. When I swipe from the right, it brings up the Action Center. When I swipe from the left, it brings up the open processes. When I swipe from the top, it brings up the voice dictate mode. I want to disable all of those behaviors but my touchpad is detected by windows as a generic HID-compliant mouse.

Everywhere I look, the default response is to install the proper drivers but the proper drivers are indeed already installed. It's just that my 2-in-1 device uses a generic touchpad so there's no hope of ever finding a feature-full driver for it like with Synaptics, etc.

So now I want to find another way to disable the gestures. Can I hack around in the registry? Can I catch those system calls so they don't execute? Anything else I can do besides "finding the correct driver" because I feel like that's just an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution offered here will only disable the touchSCREEN gestures...

I think that the touchpad is enumerating as a mouse, which is okay... but also is internally sending key combinations via it's keyboard part when you swipe - these would be Win+a win+tab Win+b and Win+b

The only way I've found to defeat these is to override the shortcut key combos themselves by setting up an "AutoHotKey" script (search for autohotkey if youre not sure what this is)
putting this in the script should stop this behaviour, but still allow touchscreen gestures to work:

```
#d::return
#a::return
#tab::return
#b::return
```

­­­­­­

Comment: Yeah, this is what I did end up doing years ago back when I asked this question but for the sake of other people stumbling across this question, I'll choose your answer

Answer (score -1):

for anyone trying to fix this issue, what ended up working for me was this:

```
#Down::return
#Tab::return
#a::return
#b::return
^WheelDown::return
^WheelUp::return
```

This disabled the touch edge gesture and the pinch to zoom gesture

Answer (score -2):

Try the following way:

1. Enter regedit in the Cortana search bar and press Enter to enter the Registry Editor.
2. Position to
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI

Note: Users without the EdgeUI item need to be manually created. Right click on Windows, select New, and rename to EdgeUI.

3. Create a new DWORD (32-bit) value in EdgeUI, rename it to AllowEdgeSwipe, and keep the value data as the default "0".
4. This modification takes effect after restarting the computer. To restore the above edge swipe gesture, change the AllowEdgeSwipe value data to "1" and restart the computer.